# Why is my convolutional neural network returning NaN after a few iterations?

Tags: java, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, overfitting-underfitting

I'm currently coding my own convolutional neural network in Java. First I implemented the fully-connected-layers which worked perfectly fine (it worked correctly with the MNIST dataset).
Now I have also implemented the convolutional layer and tried it with a really simple example:

```
Network nn = new Network(new SGD(0.01), new CrossEntropy(), new Convolution(6, 3, 3, 2),  new Convolution(4, 2, 2, 1), new Flatten());
    ConvTrainPair[] trainPairs = new ConvTrainPair[] {
        new ConvTrainPair(Cube.ones(6, 6, 3), Vector.from(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8))
    };
    
    //System.out.println(nn.run(new Cube[] {Cube.ones(6, 6, 3)}));
    for(int e = 0; e < 100000000; ++e) {
        nn.train(trainPairs, 2);
        Matrix out = (Matrix) nn.run(new Cube[] {Cube.ones(6, 6, 3)});
        System.out.println("out: " + out);
    }
```

But somehow after a few iterations the network is only returning NaN and I have no idea why. The network is just a simple network with one convolutional-layer (with input-size 6 and input-depth 3 and kernel-size 3 and numKernels 2), another one (with input-size 4 and input-depth 2 and kernel-size 2 and numKernels 1) and a final Flatten layer which turns the output into a matrix. I'm using stochastic-gradient-descent and the cross-entropy loss.

I'm quite sure that the error must be in my code of the convolution-layer:

```
public class Convolution extends Layer {
private Matrix[][] filters, filterGradients;
private Matrix[] bias, biasGradients; 
private Cube[] lastInputBatch;
private Trainer trainer;
private int trainerWW, trainerWH, trainerBL;

public Convolution(int inputSize, int inputDepth, int filterSize, int numFilters) {

    int outputSize = inputSize - filterSize + 1;
    this.trainerWW = numFilters * filterSize;
    this.trainerWH = inputDepth * filterSize;
    this.trainerBL = (numFilters + outputSize) * outputSize; 
    
    this.bias = new Matrix[numFilters];
    this.filters = new Matrix[numFilters][inputDepth];
    for(int i = 0; i < numFilters; ++i) {
        bias[i] = Matrix.random(outputSize, outputSize);
        
        for(int j = 0; j < inputDepth; ++j) {
            filters[i][j] = Matrix.random(filterSize, filterSize);
        }
    }
}



@Override
public void init(Optimizer optimizer) {
    this.trainer = new Trainer(trainerWW, trainerWH, trainerBL, optimizer);
}



@Override
public Object feedforward(Cube[] batch) {
    this.lastInputBatch = batch;
    Cube[] out = new Cube[batch.length];
    
    for(int b = 0; b < batch.length; ++b) {
        Cube current = batch[b];
        Matrix[] fMaps = new Matrix[filters.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < filters.length; ++i) {
            fMaps[i] = bias[i];
            for(int j = 0; j < filters[i].length; ++j) {
                fMaps[i].addE(crossCorrelate(current.data[j], filters[i][j]));
            }
        }
        
        out[b] = new Cube(fMaps);
    }
    
    return out;
}



@Override
public Object backward(Cube[] deltaBatch, boolean needsActivationGradient) {
    Cube[] inputDeltaBatch = new Cube[deltaBatch.length];
    for(int b = 0; b < deltaBatch.length; ++b) {
        Cube delta = deltaBatch[b];
        Cube lastInput = lastInputBatch[b];
        
        filterGradients = new Matrix[filters.length][filters[0].length];
        biasGradients = new Matrix[filterGradients.length];
        Matrix[] inputGradients = new Matrix[filters[0].length];
        for(int i = 0; i < filterGradients.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < filterGradients[i].length; ++j) {
                Matrix filter = filters[i][j];
                filterGradients[i][j] = crossCorrelate(lastInput.data[j], delta.data[i]);
                if(i == 0) inputGradients[j] = new Matrix(lastInput.width(), lastInput.height());
                inputGradients[j].addE(crossCorrelate(delta.data[i].padding(filter.w - 1), filter.rotate180()));
            }
            biasGradients[i] = delta.data[i];
        }
        
        inputDeltaBatch[b] = new Cube(inputGradients);
    }
    
    return inputDeltaBatch;
}

public static Matrix crossCorrelate(Matrix input, Matrix kernel) {
    int nmW = input.w - kernel.w + 1;
    int nmH = input.h - kernel.h + 1;
    Matrix nm = new Matrix(nmW, nmH);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nmW; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < nmH; ++j) {
            for(int a = 0; a < kernel.w; ++a) {
                for(int b = 0; b < kernel.h; ++b) {
                    nm.e[i][j] += input.e[i + a][j + b] * kernel.e[a][b];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return nm;
}



@Override
public void optimize(int episode) {
    double lr = 0.001;
    for(int i = 0; i < filters.length; ++i)  {
        for(int j = 0; j < filters[i].length; ++j) {
            //System.out.println(filters[i][j]);
            filters[i][j].subE(filterGradients[i][j].mul(lr));
        }
    }
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < bias.length; ++i) {
        bias[i].subE(biasGradients[i].mul(lr));
    }
    
    //System.out.println();
    
} }
```

I already tried to only use one convolutional-layer which solves the problem, but I don't understand why. I also tried to change the learning rate and the loss-function, but I didn't solve the problem. I also inserted some activation-functions between the two convolutional-layers and one after the flatten-layer. With the sigmoid-function it didn't return NaN anymore, but it also didn't seem to learn anything by training. With the tanH and the softmax function it still returned Nan.

If you have any idea what the problem might be, I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you performing any division?  Can the denominator be zero?

Comment: There  aren't any divisions in my convolution code and I don't think that any denominator could be zero.

Comment: The best way in my opinion is to build an exact same network in libraries like pytorch, feed the exact same input and initial weights etc. and track the output from every layer, so you can pinpoint the exact location of error.